# How to preserve insertion ordered while reading a property file?

Tags: java

How to preserve insertion ordered while reading a property file?

This question is self explained. Reading a property file is fine. But This example codes the way to preserve the reading and insertion order of all the properties from the property file. The helper class just extend the Properties and inside use Linked Hash Map to preserve the insertion order.

Comment: What example? There is no example in this question.

Comment: why would you need to preserve the order of properties?

Answer (score 0):

Let us write a custom class instead of using java.util.Properties, our code will manage everything like: reading the property file, splitting the key value pair, maintain the order of the properties as the appear in the file, etc. Here is a sample code:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CustomProperty {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> properties = parse("test.properties");
        System.out.println(properties);
    }

    public static Map<String, String> parse(String filePath) {
        Map<String, String> properties = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Scanner sc;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                try {
                    String[] tokens = sc.nextLine().split("=");
                    properties.put(tokens[0].trim(), tokens[1].trim());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return properties;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    **application.properties**

    banner.charset=UTF-8
    banner.location=classpath:banner.txt

    server.port=8080
    server.contextPath=/test
    spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
    spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

    server.session.timeout=18000
    server.session.cookie.max-age=18000
    management.security.enabled=false
    security.basic.enabled=false
    a=1
    b=2

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Enumeration;
    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import java.util.Set;

    // Load and Read a property file from class path

    public class Load_and_Print_a_Property_File_From_Classpath2 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            PreserveInsertionOrderedProperties prop = new PreserveInsertionOrderedProperties();
            InputStream input = null;
            String filename = "application.properties";
            try {

                input = Load_and_Print_a_Property_File_From_Classpath2.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
                if (input == null) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filename);
                    return;
                }
                prop.load(input);

                LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> keyValueSet = prop.keyValueSet;
                for (Object key : keyValueSet.keySet()) {
                    System.out.println("Key = " + key + " | " + "Value = " + keyValueSet.get(key));
                }


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (input != null) {
                    try {
                        input.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class PreserveInsertionOrderedProperties extends Properties {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> keyValueSet = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();

        @Override
        public Enumeration<Object> keys() {
            return Collections.enumeration(keyValueSet.keySet());
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Object> keySet() {
            return keyValueSet.keySet();
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized Object put(Object key, Object value) {
            if (!keyValueSet.containsValue(key)) 
                keyValueSet.put(key.toString(), value.toString());
            return keyValueSet.get(key);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized Object remove(Object key) {
            return keyValueSet.remove(key);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void putAll(Map values) {
            for (Object key : values.keySet()) {
                if (!containsKey(key)) {
                    keyValueSet.putAll(values);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    **After print**

    Key = banner.charset | Value = UTF-8

    Key = banner.location | Value = classpath:banner.txt

    Key = server.port | Value = 8080

    Key = server.contextPath | Value = /test

    Key = spring.mvc.view.prefix | Value = /WEB-INF/jsp/

    Key = spring.mvc.view.suffix | Value = .jsp

    Key = server.session.timeout | Value = 18000

    Key = server.session.cookie.max-age | Value = 18000

    Key = management.security.enabled | Value = false

    Key = security.basic.enabled | Value = false

    Key = a | Value = 1

    Key = b | Value = 2
```

Comment: Bad implementation, giving different results depending on use.